# What's the difference between these two definitions of Fourier transformation of measure?

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\Bbb R^d$. I met the following two definitions of Fourier transformation of $\mu$ in the textbook:

1. $\displaystyle \widehat{\mu}(\xi)=\int e^{i\xi\cdot x}d\mu(x)$;
2. $\displaystyle \widehat{\mu}(\xi)=\int e^{-2\pi i\xi\cdot x}d\mu(x)$.

My question is: what's the difference between these two definitions of Fourier transformation of measure?

Comment: Do you mean $\widehat{\mu}(\xi)=\int e^{-i\xi\cdot x}d\mu(x)$ in the first case?

Comment: @Sayan: Not necessarilly. That one is *yet another* convention...

Comment: No, Sayan. The first case is just as I gave.

Comment: A nice feature of definition 2 is that it removes the need for a prefactor on the inverse transformation. On the other hand every derivative pops out a factor of $-2\pi  i\xi$ which can be annoying when working with differential equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both conventions are used (in fact, [Wikipedia list three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Other_conventions)). Some are more appropriate in an electrical engineering context, some in a quantum-mechanical context and some in pure mathematics. The underlying mathematics are the same, some constant factors will differ, though. They are all correct.

Comment: Many thanks, Alex M.